# Finding highest score of alignment between substrings/suffix etc

Tags: algorithm, matrix, substring, alignment, traceback

so I am working on my assignment and I ran out into a problem that I can't really google. I don't really understand what the questions are asking me because they all look like they are asking for the same thing to me. Here are the questions:

X=QRSWCHAW
Y=WHLAWT

1.Explain how we can find the highest score of an alignment between substring of X and the whole string Y in the matrix that I have previously calculated. Write down optimal alignment between substring of X and the string Y.
2.Explain how we can find the highest score of an alignment between a suffix of X and the whole string Y in the matrix F that you have calculated in part (a). Write down an optimal alignment between a suffix of X and the string Y.
3.Explain how we can find the highest score of an alignment between a substring of X and a prefix of Y in the matrix F that you have calculated in part (a). Write down an optimal alignment between a substring of X and a prefix of Y.

All of these are only worth 2 marks each, so I don't know if I am overthinking this problem. If someone could explain what I am asked to do. Do they need a code or just a simple word explanation? Preferably through example because I looked everywhere on the internet and books but didn't find anything.

I think that these would give the same alignments for all the questions. And I can find it by a traceback? Or do I need to do a local alignment?

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by alignment?

Comment: I need to align these two sequences together in a way that the outcome will give the highest score. e.g. I got an alignment score of -3 for the alignment that looks like this:Q-,R-,S-,WW,CH,HL,AA,WW,-T. Where '-' is a gap. First letters are the letters of X and second of Y. e.g.(Q from X is aligned to - (gap) of Y)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your score and alignment are, but I can tell you how those questions are different.

- A substring is a chunk out of the string from any position to any other.  So `SWCH` is a substring of `QRSWCHAW`.  You can specify it with 2 numbers, the start and end positions.
- A suffix starts somewhere and goes to the end.  So `WCHAW` is a suffix of `QRSWCHAW`.  You can specify it with 1 number, the start position.
- A prefix starts at the beginning then ends somewhere.  So `WHL` is a prefix of `WHLAWT`.  You can specify it with 1 number, the end position.

With that your questions can all be written as nested loops to run over all of the possibilities, then a function call in the middle to get the score.  Keep track of the best score seen so far.

Comment: Hi, so for 1. I said: Start traceback at largest value in column m, until row 0 is reached. Optimal alignment in this case: QW,RH,-L,SA,WW,CT and the optimal alignment score is 6. Is this correct or am I answering a completely different thing?